# Show logged in user data asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Which is the best way to expose current logged in user data to many different views?

I am thinking something like the Model variable but accessible to all view but wasn't able to find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You an access the user property from any view with

```
@User
```

For example (C#),

```
@{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <p>Hello, @User.Identity.Name</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't workout because i have an Associated table to the existing Membership System that extends the Data of the User like Name,Surname,Location etc

Comment: For that I recommend [extending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) the `IPrincipal`. In future I recommend you include more information in your question. Your question is very short with no description of your situation or what you are trying to achieve. This means you get an equally short and generic answer.